Why will the Coanda effect make a piece of paper bend?
There is an answer here that explains the Coanda effect very well in my opinion.
To summarize, the Coanda effect is when a stream of air flowing will ‘pull along’ the air molecules beside it, mainly due to viscosity and turbulent mixing. When it pulls the molecules along, where the molecules once were is now a void, making low pressure. (If that didn’t make sense, check out the answer linked)
Now this low pressure being made requires the surrounding air, so the stream has something to pull along. When the stream of air is right next to a surface, why is there still low pressure created (as evidenced by the piece of paper bending)?
There could still be lower pressure on the other side of the stream as there’s not a surface or piece of paper next to the flow, but that wouldn’t change if the piece of paper bent or not.

Can a real stream be “right next to a wall”?

@Chemomechanics Interesting, the boundary layer is something I did think of. Thanks.

This is actually easy to explain.

Assuming that the air at the top of the paper strip moves horizontally in the direction of the blue arrow, due to the curved surface of the paper strip, the air in the small wedge-shaped space at the red arrow will be carried away due to viscosity. As a result, the pressure of the air in this wedge-shaped space will decrease, and the horizontally moving air will bend downward. In this way, the air moving horizontally will move along the curved surface of the paper strip.
